# Unable to send form data using axios from my frontend. Getting Network error. But when I tried to hit the backend from postman it is working fine

Tags: node.js, reactjs, axios

I have written below. I tried without adding headers and with headers. I have added the headers in the middlewares in my backed. But I'm still getting the network error. Any suggestions would be helpful

```
this.data = {
  name: this.state.name,
  email: this.state.email,
  username: this.state.username,
  password: this.state.password,
};

this.headers = {
  'Content-Type': 'application/json; charset=utf-8',
  Accept: 'application/json',
};
Axios.post('http://localhost:8080/api/auth/signup', this.data, this.headers)
  .then((res) => {
    console.log(res);
  })
  .catch((err) => {
    console.log(err);
  });
```

Comment: Hi, it's easiest for us to answer your question if you post all of the pertinent information. Please post the error that you are getting, and the working backend code at least. Thanks!

Comment: If it is working from the postman, that means the browser is doing something. For example, attaching headers, sending options request, ..etc.